# Problemas com o angular - NPM

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

**Quando eu dou um npm install no meu projeto, ele me volta esse erro :**

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1103:38)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:637:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:467:38)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\UsersTLF\\Desktop\\interface-pesquisa-textual\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\UsersTLF\Desktop\interface-pesquisa-textual\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.7.2 (node_modules\node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

**E quando eu dou um ng serve ele apresenta esse erro:**

```
ERROR in ./src/app/pesquisa/ato-pessoal/pesquisa-ato-pessoal.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
```

Alguém já passou por isso ?

Comment: Talvez esses [Issue 979](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/979) ajude a corrigir seu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Este erro é porque o node-sass não está presente. Para resolver isso é só você executar o seguinte comando

```
npm install node-sass
```